# How can i Check the object names from collision?

Tags: c#

[image: Example]

I want to move the red circle to another box position which is only collide with current square game object.

In my current code like if a click an one of the that game object (squares). position of the red circle will be equal the position of the square which i clicked. i need to move the red circle just the neighbor squares. Using collision or some other style how can i make that logic easly?

Comment: If you have colliders the collision well tell you what you hit, if you stored a position, you would know where you are.. choices are yours

Comment: "Collision" isn't what you should be looking for here. Collision occurs when two objects bump into each other (which inherently means **at least one** object is moving). Your squares are (presumably) static, and therefore you shouldn't be using collision logic. A much better approach is to either define the square's neighbors (as properties of the square) or have top-level grid logic to find the neighbors dynamically. _Note: I'm sure you can find something hacky that works and uses collisions; but it won't be a good solution and it will require you to misuse the collider logic._

Comment: @Flater I can make a data for each squares neighbors like for example neighbor of square 1 are square 2,5,6. But its look not usefull  for me i will check the grid logic.

Comment: @SalimDilek: `for example neighbor of square 1 are square 2,5,6` Shouldn't it be **2,7,8**? Also, I highy suggest using two integers (columnindex + rowindex) to denote your squares instead of a single integer (sequential ID) specifically to prevent issues like you (presumably) miscounting the order of squares.

Comment: @Flater Yes true 2,7,8. Actually with specific size of object like those squares i can measure the distance easily. Like if the squares are 50x50 size my circle only can move the distance of the target object coordinate less than 51 so it was worked actually i already tried. But i forgot the explain complex situations like neighbor object but different shapes. For example a country map and im at one city i can only go to neighbor cities. In that case its hard to make a logic with colums and rows.

Comment: @SalimDilek: Whether it's a grid or a gridless map, you'll always be required to **define what constitues a neighbor**. Your question already explicitly tells us your current definition of a neighbor: _adjacent, but not diagonal_.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

Implementation:

```
public class StackOverflowScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Detector CircleObject;

    public SquareItem SquarePrefab;
    public Vector2 SpawnOffset;

    List<SquareItem> _squares = new List<SquareItem>();

    private void Start()
    {
        InitGrid();
    }

    public void InitGrid()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 6; j++)
            {
                var pos = new Vector2(i, j) * SpawnOffset;
                SquareItem square = Instantiate(SquarePrefab, pos, Quaternion.identity) as SquareItem;
                square.Init(this, pos);
                _squares.Add(square);
            }
        }
    }

    public void MoveCircle(SquareItem item, Vector2 newPos)
    {
        if (CircleObject.Squares.Contains(item))
            CircleObject.MoveTowardPos(newPos);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class SquareItem : MonoBehaviour
{
    private StackOverflowScript _stackScript;

    public Vector2 Position
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    public void Init(StackOverflowScript script, Vector2 squarePosition)
    {
        _stackScript = script;
        Position = squarePosition;
    }


    private void OnMouseDown()
    {
        _stackScript.MoveCircle(this, this.transform.position);
    }
}
```

---

```
using System.Linq;

public class Detector : MonoBehaviour
{
    public List<SquareItem> Squares
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    public float DetectionRadius = 2f;

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        Collider2D[] colliders = Physics2D.OverlapCircleAll(this.transform.position, DetectionRadius);

        Squares = colliders.ToList().FindAll(el => el.GetComponent<SquareItem>() != null).Select(el => el.GetComponent<SquareItem>()).ToList();
    }

    //This is for drawing the red circle in the inspector so you can control the radius of detection.
    private void OnDrawGizmos()
    {
        Gizmos.color = Color.red;
        Gizmos.DrawWireSphere(this.transform.position, DetectionRadius);
    }

    public void MoveTowardPos(Vector2 newPos)
    {
        this.transform.position = newPos;
    }
}
```

Explanation:

StackOverflowScript is used to initiate the grid of square and controlling the movement of the circle.

SquareItem is the script attached for every square you instantiate, it contains the position information for now.

Detector is the script attached to your circle/ player and it tests with Physics2D Overlaps if there are squares in the neighbor within certain radius.

When the square item is pressed it send its informations to stackoverflow script who is responsible to check if the square is in the detection radius of the circle. If so, move the circle to the square position.

Hope this helps!

[Execution Gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/3q3LcIFh7XNYiZGHMj/giphy.mp4)

Cheers!